# How to mock my superclass in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec3

I have the following code:

```
class Blurk
  def initialize
    # horror
  end

  def perform
    # yet more horror
  end
end

class Grunf < Blurk
   def perform
     super
     # here some code to test
   end
end
```

I would like to test the code on `Grunf#perform` but I can't figure out how to mock `Blurk`.

Comment: You can redefine `Blurk#perform` when you test `Grunf` or (I think, better), you can test `Blurk` well as a unit, and test `Grunf` also as a unit. That is, making no assumption about whether it subclasses something else or not, but assuming that the "rest is valid".

Comment: In RSpec, you may try the combination `allow().to_receive().and_return()` as well to control the call to `super`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you shouldn't do it. A better approach (IMHO) is to make some slight changes to your class definitions

```
class Blurk
  def initialize
    # horror
  end

  def perform
    # yet more horror
    exec_perform
  end
  
  protected
  
  def exec_perform
    raise "exec_perform must be overriden"
  end
end

class Grunf < Blurk
   def exec_perform
     # here some code to test
   end
end
```

and to test `Blurk` and `Grunf` separately (in `Blurk` tests you may create `TestClass` definition in order to confirm `exec_perform` is run as expected). In `Grunf`'s test file you would just test the `exec_perform` method.